# On object(copy) parameter change original changes

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is not a question on "How to" but "Why"

I have observed some wird object behaviour in JS on Chrome(36.0.1985.125).
If i copy object to diffrent variable and change that copy data original object changes.

How is that possible?

Here is the code that matters:

```
var argsForNewAjax = false;

function news_ajax(args, id){
    var ajaxStartTime = new Date().getTime();
    var temp = argsForNewAjax;
    if(argsForNewAjax){
        args = argsForNewAjax;
    }
    else{
        args.action = "get_news";
        args.numberposts = (isDefined(args.numberposts) ? args.numberposts : 4);
    }
    argsForNewAjax = jQuery.extend({}, args); //if i change this line to the one comented
    //argsForNewAjax = args
    argsForNewAjax.offset = argsForNewAjax.offset + args.numberposts;

    console.log(args);
    $.ajax({
    //JQ ajax ...
```

result with jquery.extend

- object is copied and updated and args stay un-changed

widouth jquery

- object is copied but when it's value changes original(args) change

So my question is how can a value change if it's copy changes in JS?

Comment: It is basic concept ... here value is pass by reference and not by value

Comment: Now this is embarrassing didn't even think of that. Thanks pointing that out.

Comment: No problem ... sometime we are so focused on other part of the code that we are not able to think about basic things.

Comment: So let me extend the why question - why does js do it this way? Why is that useful? Since y = x point to the same object, I might as well just use x. And if I want a copy of the object, what then? Seems js devs were smoking something!

Comment: . Using jquery extend you will be able to copy widouth reference